# FQL query returning empty array

Tags: arrays, facebook, api, facebook-fql, empy

FQL query returning empty.

I run the following FQL in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer:

```
SELECT uid, name, username, birthday_date, current_location, online_presence FROM user WHERE relationship_status ='Single' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

She successfully returns all my friends who are single.

However, when I run the PHP, nothing is returned:

```
$fql = "SELECT uid, name, username, birthday_date, current_location, online_presence FROM user WHERE relationship_status ='Single' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0";

$solteiros = $facebook->api(array(
                  'method'       => 'fql.query',
                  'access_token' => $userAccessToken,
                  'query'        => $fql,
                ));
```

Until yesterday it was working fine.
Today when I test, it happened.

Answer (score 1):

If it runs in the Explorer and not in your PHP app, you are most likely seeing a difference in access token clearance. That is, the access token supplied to Explorer has the permissions needed while the token used for your app does not.

Verify by calling `/me/permissions` on your PHP application to see what is there.

Your site also gives an invalid api key error

[image: Invalid API Key]

Comment: I Run app in www.tasolteiro.com

The returns address all your friends who are unmarried:
https://tasolteiro.com/fb-friends/all

Before returning correctly, now no more.

Comment: See above... the image is there.

Comment: How strange.
The application was functioning normally.
Checked now and saw that he was excluded.

Why is it? could imagine why?

Comment: No idea, if your app was removed the only option now would be to go to   https://developers.facebook.com/appeal